# Complex Arithmetic Expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell, arithmetic-expressions

How can i perform complex arithmetic calculation in haskell ?

**Example :**

```
eval numb(1) = 1 
eval (add(numb(1),numb(2))) = 3 
eval (add(mult(numb(1),numb(2)),diff(numb(3),numb(4)))) = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much just like that, but with some slight syntax tweaks so you're speaking GHC's language.

```
data Expr = Numb Int | Add Expr Expr | Diff Expr Expr | Mult Expr Expr

eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Numb x) = x
eval (Add e e') = eval e + eval e'
eval (Diff e e') = eval e - eval e'
eval (Mult e e') = eval e * eval e'
```

In ghci:

```
> eval (Numb 1)
1
> eval (Add (Numb 1) (Numb 2))
3
> eval (Add (Mult (Numb 1) (Numb 2)) (Diff (Numb 3) (Numb 4)))
1
```

Comment: wow, thanks @Daniel Wagner. Saved my day. Plus, you expressed in such a simple way. Is there any reference (link, book) you would refer so as master haskell ?

Comment: @CosmicBadal Look at the end of the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info).